# Bootstrap Off Canvas Left navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build responsive layout for webpage using bootstrap. I would like to render the webpage normally with header, left navigation on large displays[desktop resolutions]. But I would like to show toggle button if the site is resized to that of tablets or mobile device [OffCanvas Bootstrap]. Below is what i have achieved so far..

**JsFiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/222/**

Now,I'm having issues with slide animation and left navigation visibility[always hidden]. If anyone can spot where I'm going wrong will be appreciated.. thanks

```
<section class="offcanvas-layout">
    <aside id="aside-menu" class="offcanvas-left nav-collapse collapse">
        <div id="leftcontent">
            <div class="inner">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li> <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>United States</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>Canada</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
    </aside>
    <article class="offcanvas-content">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="btn navbar-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aside-menu">Click Me</button> <a id="logo">Logo here</a>

                <div class="dropdown pull-right"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="searchBox">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                        <input id="header-search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search..." /> <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="search_Button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="maincontent">
            <div id="maincontentnav">
                <p>Main Content Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: You'll need media queries to address the different screen/canvas width.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/ This example may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `visible-xs` responsive utility class like this...

`<button class="btn navbar-btn visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aside-menu">Click Me</button> <a id="logo">Logo here</a>`

http://bootply.com/130279

Comment: Hi Baghoo, Thanks for comment. I have already considered that but I would like the left navigation visible on large, medium[visible-lg, .visible-md]  and If I use [.visible-xs, .visible-sm] on the button as suggested by you. They don't play well together. I would like to see the botton visible as soon as  the left navigation disappear